# Control consumption of multiple JMS queues

Tags: spring, spring-jms

I can't find this information anywhere. I have two queues, `@JmsListener(destination = "p1")`, `@JmsListener(destination = "p2")`. How can I make sure I only process 1 message at a time, even though I am listening to 2 queues, and also how do I configure the polling of what queue I get messages from first, that is after processing a message I want to poll `p1` first. Or do weighted polling: `p1`:90%, `p2`:10%. Etc.

Basically I am asking how to implement priority processing of messages for `Spring`. I'm using `SQS` which doesn't support priorities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the `JmsTemplate` `receive()` or `receiveAndConvert()` methods instead of the message-driven model.

Use transactions if you want to ensure no message loss.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I need a little bit for guidance on how to use the `JmsTemplate` to achieve this, so do I override this method? And what should I do within it? And what do transactions have to do with this question?

Comment: Override which method? You can call one of the receive methods whenever you want, on whichever queue you want. Normally, `receive()` methods will acknowledge the message immediately; you need to run in a transaction so the message removal won't be committed until the method performing the receive exits.