# What happens when you have multiple JMS listeners in Spring competing for processing resources?

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

What happens if I have many `@JmsListener(destination = ...)`, listening for messages on different queues. Who gets to listen first, how can I control this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot control the fine level behavior in any meaningful way; work is scheduled by the operating system scheduler.

You can control the behavior at a gross level by starting/stopping the listener containers - give the listeners an `id` property and start/stop the containers via the `JmsListenerEndpointRegistry` bean.

But you can't "control consumption" per your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59277342/control-consumption-of-multiple-jms-queues/59277497#59277497). I suggested there to use the `JmsTemplate` instead.